# What platforms JavaFX is/will be supported on?

Tags: java, javafx

I have read about JavaFX, and like all new technologies I wanted to get my hands "dirty" with it. However, although it talks of multiplatform support, I can't find specifics on this.

What platforms support a JavaFX application? All those with Java SE? ME? Does it depend upon the APIs in JavaFX that I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaFX has three planned distributions.

- JavaFX Desktop will run on Windows, Mac, <s>Linux, and Solaris</s> at FCS and will require Java SE.  Support for Linux and Solaris will be forthcoming.
- JavaFX TV and JavaFX Mobile have no announce target platforms.  Also unannounced is whether they will run on ME or SE, and if ME which profiles.

One important platform distinction is that JavaFX Desktop will support Swing components while JavaFX Mobile will not (only scene graph for graphics).   JavaFX TV the least publicly concrete of the three at this time.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see JavaFX is a whole new runtime and compiler so is not a subset of Java. Sun will support it on mobile phones and on the desktop.

OS-wise it is currently released for Windows/Mac but Solaris/Linux are in the works.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFx is not a new runtime. It is the same JRE but a new language/compiler with some a few new APIs to make it all works....

Using Netbeans, you can build applications on any platform.  As of today, the APIs are beta. Classfiles produced by the compiler are JRE 6 compatible.