# What does a mobile need to be able to run JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

What exactly does a mobile need to be able to run JavaFX? Can it run on any mobile that supports specific JSRs or does it have to be installed by the manufacturer?

**Links**

- [What platforms JavaFX is/will be supported on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129/what-platforms-javafx-is-will-be-supported-on)? - Doesn't go into any detail about specific mobile platforms
- [JavaFX/Mobile Devices](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?forumID=932&threadID=5366817) - This question (February 2009) says that although manufactor support is preferred, many MSA-compliant phones will be able to handle an over the air player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be installed by the manufacturer.

For development purposes you can use the developer stack for Windows Mobile.

http://javafx.com/downloads/all.jsp

Comment: This is true for the moment - eventually they plan to release an over the air version